# from ftp ssl to Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, delphi, ssl, amazon-s3, ftp

I have a system that works with FTP over SSL in Delphi XE5, but I am planning to switch to Amazon S3. 
I'm trying to make a straightforward set of commans that will set parameters, connect, put files in bucket and disconnect.

Right now I'm doing this with IDFTP

```
ftp := TIdFTP.Create();
  ssl := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(ftp);
  ftp.IOHandler := ssl;
  ssl.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23;
  ftp.UseTLS := utUseExplicitTLS;
  ftp.Host := 'myftpserver.com';
  ftp.Username := 'user';
  ftp.Password := 'password';
  ftp.Passive := true;
  ftp.Connect;
  ftp.ChangeDir(destinefolder);

for i := 1 to3 do    
begin               //upload  file1.jpg, file2.jpg, file3.jpg
ftp.put (local + ‘file’ + inttostr(i) + ’.jpg’ , ‘file’ + inttostr(i), true, false);
end;

ssl.Free;
 ftp.Free;
```

It works nice for FTPS.

I have read people saying that it is possible to use IDhttp for Amazon S3.

I wonder if there is a simple way to adapt my ftps  to amazon s3.

Comment: So what is the actual problem you are having? You need to be more specific, don't just throw a bunch of code around without explaining what it does (or does not) do.  Are you getting errors? If so, what are they? Are you getting unexpected behavior? If so, what is it, and what are expecting instead? What have you tried so far to troubleshoot the problem?

Comment: Sorry about that. I have 2 example projects on Delphi that access S3: Cloud explorer, that works perfectly, and PC Plus S3 Example (http://www.itwriting.com/s3.php ) that only list buckets correctly (won´t get or put files nor list objects). But even so, they are too complex for what I need. 
I only need to put files into a bucket.
I have:
Access Key Id
Secret Access Key
Bucket name
File Name
That should be enough for uploading a file.
I need to know how to build a string, I guess, to use IDHTTP.Put(… to send the file to the Amazon S3 server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the AWS documentation:

[PUT Object](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html)

[Authenticating a Request in the Authorization Header](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-auth-using-authorization-header.html)

Try this:

```
Auth := '...'; // calculate/format based on Access Key Id Secret Access Key...

for i := 1 to 3 do    
begin         
  FS := TFileStream.Create(local + 'file' + inttostr(i) + '.jpg', fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
  try
    IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Authorization'] := Auth;
    IdHTTP1.Request.BasicAuthentication := False;
    IdHTTP1.Request.Date := ...;
    IdHTTP1.Request.Expect := '100-continue';
    IdHTTP1.Request.ProtocolVersion := pv1_1;
    // other headers as needed...
    ...
    IdHTTP1.Put('http://'+BucketName+'.s3.amazonaws.com/file' + inttostr(i), FS);
  finally
    FS.Free;
  end;
end;
```